# Kivy imports SDL2, GLEW and ANGLE when new process start

Tags: kivy, python-multiprocessing

I need to use `Python Multiprocessing` for some `CPU Bound` task. When I run my app and new process is created I see in `kivy log` that it imports a `kivy.deps` and some more stuff again. It takes a lot of time and it looks like `window` is created again. Why is that happening? I expected the app to just create new process and do only what `MyProcess` class is for.

**LOG**

```
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Patryk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Random\venv_python\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Patryk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Random\venv_python\Scripts\python.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 441.66'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVS 510/PCIe/SSE2'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
    [**IMPORTING DEPS AGAIN**]
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Patryk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Random\venv_python\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Patryk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Random\venv_python\Scripts\python.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    MP RUN
    [INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

**MY CODE**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from multiprocessing import Process

kv = '''    
MyWindow:
'''


class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print('MP RUN')


class MyWindow(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        mp = MyProcess()
        mp.start()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure offhand exactly what the new process inherits, but in this case you're clearly using it to run Python code that includes your kivy imports. Maybe you should use a separate file that doesn't include the imports you don't want, but I'm not sure what is the intention. The multiprocessing documentation may say something about the best way to avoid it.

Comment: This is just a snippet that shows the issue. In my real code a use a separate file exacly as you wrote.

Comment: I've just tried to do the same with `threading` and no such issue. Must be something with how the process is created.

Comment: Just using a separate file won't help if the process entry point is the same - you're likely setting up the python process just the same way. It's normal that threading doesn't do the same thing because threads don't involve a separate process loading the module again.